# Weird behavior in Struts2

Tags: java, struts2

I was working on Struts and encountered some strange behavior. Though it is not creating any errors or bugs I just thought it would be interesting to share it with you folks.

Perhaps one of you can explain why this is happening.

Create a Struts action with following code -

```
public class MyAction extends ActionSupport {
    private Map<String, Map<String, Object>> map = new HashMap<String, Map<String, Object>>();
    public String execute() {
        System.out.println(map);
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public Map<String, Map<String, Object>> getMap() {
        return map;
    }

    public void setMap(Map<String, Map<String, Object>> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }
}
```

Create associated mappings and Jsp required and execute the action.
You will see following output on the console -

```
{systemProperties={java.runtime.name=Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment, sun.boot.library.path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_32\jre\bin, java.vm.version=20.7-b02, shared.loader=${catalina.base}/shared/classes ....
```

So apparently Struts is injecting the system properties into my map.
But why is it doing so? I didn't ask it to do so. There is no special XML configuration or annotation that I've used.
What part of Struts (what interceptor) is responsible for this? Have I just discovered a bug or is this normal behavior? If it's normal why the heck did Struts developer think it'd be wise to inject every `Map<String, Map<String, Object>>` with system properties?

Comment: Have set `autowire` parameter in your spring config XML?

Comment: @plucury Why would that make a difference? Spring injects bean dependencies. It doesn't inject collections.

Comment: Spring would inject any type of properties if it has set method.

Comment: @plucury Inject from where if we don't configure it? If I have setContact() would it create a contact by itself and inject it? Don't I need to configure a Contact Bean?

Comment: Auto wiring will look in the *entire* context, so if there was a suitable bean named "contact", it *would* inject it.

Comment: What version of Struts2 are you using?  What interceptor stack?  What object factory?

Comment: @rees Struts 2.3, struts-default interceptor stack, org.apache.struts2.spring.StrutsSpringObjectFactory

Comment: @DaveNewton Please read the comments above before commenting. I already said - "Don't I need to configure a Contact Bean?" If there is no such bean there won't be any injection. If I'd configured such a bean I'd know. Btw what possible bean could match Map<String, Map<String, Object>>?

Comment: @KshitizSharma You think I didn't read them? You missed the point: the *entire* context will be searched, not just beans *you* configured. Which bean? Apparently one w/ Java properties in it. Good luck!

Comment: @DaveNewton Lemme see if I get you right. Are you suggesting there is some preconfigured default context apart from application context that programmer configures? And I don't understand your second point. If a bean has a Map property would it get injected. How about integer properties? Do they get injected wherever integers are needed? AFAIK only bean dependencies with exact match in class type get autowired. Bean members/attributes don't qualify.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this myself and my guess was correct.
The code you have put out here does not produce any such results. You can easily spot this yourself by looking at the code. Nothing is populating the map, it is only getters and setters.

`"So apparently Struts is injecting the system properties into my map"`

If you pass a parameter to this action, for example with a form, Struts will look for its corresponding setter-method in the action. This would indicate that somewhere in your code, your form or maybe by parameter, you have something called `"map"` passed along to this Action.

Start by looking in your `struts.xml` and see if you are setting some parameters there. If not then look closely at where you are calling the action from and what parameters you send it. Then you should be able to find where you are passing in the map.

Comment: Could you share a zip of your test app? I tried it and it did produce that result for me.

Comment: Did you try it "clean"? Make a new ActionClass called MyAction2 from your code. Then create a struts.xml mapping to `<action name="testAction" class="MyAction2"></action>. Then go to localhost/testAction to test it. You will probably get some sort of 404, but then look at your output. Map should be empty. If it is not empty then it means something in your app is setting the property "map". This could mean your Action is Extending something or you might have some interceptors doing funky stuff